# Unable to connect to Cassandra db through Kundera in Play! framework

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, cql, cassandra-2.0, kundera

I am getting the following error when I run my application through SBT Console in Intellij IDEA.

```
[info] play - Application started (Dev)
[error] c.i.c.c.t.ThriftClientFactory - Error during pool creation: caused by 
org.apache.thrift.TException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Read a negative frame size (-2080374784)!
    at net.dataforte.cassandra.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:345) ~[cassandra-connection-pool-0.7.1.jar:na]
    at net.dataforte.cassandra.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:127) ~[cassandra-connection-pool-0.7.1.jar:na]
    at com.impetus.client.cassandra.thrift.ThriftClientFactory.createPoolOrConnection(ThriftClientFactory.java:146) ~[kundera-cassandra-2.5.jar:na]
    at com.impetus.kundera.loader.GenericClientFactory.load(GenericClientFactory.java:95) [kundera-core-2.5.jar:na]
    at com.impetus.kundera.configure.ClientFactoryConfiguraton.configure(ClientFactoryConfiguraton.java:67) [kundera-core-2.5.jar:na]
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Read a negative frame size (-2080374784)!
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFastFramedTransport.readFrame(TFastFramedTransport.java:144) ~[libthrift-0.7.0.jar:0.7.0]
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFastFramedTransport.read(TFastFramedTransport.java:134) ~[libthrift-0.7.0.jar:0.7.0]
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:84) ~[libthrift-0.7.0.jar:0.7.0]
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:378) ~[libthrift-0.7.0.jar:0.7.0]
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:297) ~[libthrift-0.7.0.jar:0.7.0]
[error] application - 

! Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at models.process.EmployeeProcessImpl$.<init>(EmployeeProcess.scala:82) ~[myEntities.jar:na]
    at models.process.EmployeeProcessImpl$.<clinit>(EmployeeProcess.scala) ~[myEntities.jar:na]
    at controllers.Application$.<init>(Application.scala:168) ~[na:na]
    at controllers.Application$.<clinit>(Application.scala) ~[na:na]
    at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(routes_routing.scala:107) ~[na:na]
Caused by: com.impetus.kundera.loader.ClientLoaderException: org.apache.thrift.TException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Read a negative frame size (-2080374784)!
    at com.impetus.client.cassandra.thrift.ThriftClientFactory.createPoolOrConnection(ThriftClientFactory.java:151) ~[kundera-cassandra-2.5.jar:na]
    at com.impetus.kundera.loader.GenericClientFactory.load(GenericClientFactory.java:95) ~[kundera-core-2.5.jar:na]
    at com.impetus.kundera.configure.ClientFactoryConfiguraton.configure(ClientFactoryConfiguraton.java:67) ~[kundera-core-2.5.jar:na]
    at com.impetus.kundera.configure.Configurator.configure(Configurator.java:65) ~[kundera-core-2.5.jar:na]
    at com.impetus.kundera.KunderaPersistence.initializeKundera(KunderaPersistence.java:109) ~[kundera-core-2.5.jar:na]
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.TException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Read a negative frame size (-2080374784)!
    at net.dataforte.cassandra.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:345) ~[cassandra-connection-pool-0.7.1.jar:na]
    at net.dataforte.cassandra.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:127) ~[cassandra-connection-pool-0.7.1.jar:na]
    at com.impetus.client.cassandra.thrift.ThriftClientFactory.createPoolOrConnection(ThriftClientFactory.java:146) ~[kundera-cassandra-2.5.jar:na]
    at com.impetus.kundera.loader.GenericClientFactory.load(GenericClientFactory.java:95) ~[kundera-core-2.5.jar:na]
    at com.impetus.kundera.configure.ClientFactoryConfiguraton.configure(ClientFactoryConfiguraton.java:67) ~[kundera-core-2.5.jar:na]
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Read a negative frame size (-2080374784)!
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFastFramedTransport.readFrame(TFastFramedTransport.java:144) ~[libthrift-0.7.0.jar:0.7.0]
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFastFramedTransport.read(TFastFramedTransport.java:134) ~[libthrift-0.7.0.jar:0.7.0]
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:84) ~[libthrift-0.7.0.jar:0.7.0]
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:378) ~[libthrift-0.7.0.jar:0.7.0]
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:297) ~[libthrift-0.7.0.jar:0.7.0]
[error] application - Error while rendering default error page
scala.MatchError: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError (of class java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError)
    at play.api.GlobalSettings$class.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:148) ~[play_2.11-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at play.api.DefaultGlobal$.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:206) [play_2.11-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at play.core.server.Server$class.logExceptionAndGetResult$1(Server.scala:76) [play_2.11-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at play.core.server.Server$$anonfun$getHandlerFor$4.apply(Server.scala:86) [play_2.11-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at play.core.server.Server$$anonfun$getHandlerFor$4.apply(Server.scala:84) [play_2.11-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
```

The example I am working with is taken from :
http://blog.knoldus.com/2014/06/22/playing-kundera-cassandra/

I am having Play! 2.4.6 framework with Cassandra 2.2. What could be wrong with the project which is not allowing to connect to  the database ? Do I need to make some change regarding CQL or Kundera version so that my database can get connected ? My persistence.xml file is as under:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
    https://raw.github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera/Kundera-2.0.4/kundera-core/src/test/resources/META-INF/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="cassandra_employees">
        <provider>com.impetus.kundera.KunderaPersistence</provider>
        <class>models.domains.Employee</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="kundera.nodes" value="localhost" />
            <property name="kundera.port" value="9042" />
            <property name="kundera.keyspace" value="EmployeeExample" />
            <property name="kundera.dialect" value="cassandra" />
            <property name="kundera.client.lookup.class" value="com.impetus.client.cassandra.thrift.ThriftClientFactory" />
            <property name="kundera.cache.provider.class" value="com.impetus.kundera.cache.ehcache.EhCacheProvider" />
            <property name="kundera.cache.config.resource" value="/ehcache-test.xml" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Please tell me if I have to make some version related change for Cassandra or CQL and that too in which file ?

Comment: What could be the reason that the database is not getting connected ? What more configuration related change is required so as to connect Cassandra db from my local system. I have installed Play! framework and Cassandra on a single system itself, but yet not being able to connect Cassandra db from my code. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: change the port to `9160` and you can remove `kundera.cache.provider.class` and `kundera.cache.config.resource` properties..

Comment: The port for `native_transport_port` is 9042 in cassandra.yaml file. So 9160 would work fine in that case or not ? Also should I change it to 9160 in `persistence.xml` only or `cassandra.yaml` file as well ?

Comment: As of now its showing the below error:
`com.impetus.kundera.KunderaException: All hosts are down. please check servers manully.`

Comment: dont change the port in `cassandra.yaml`.. port that Kundera uses is `rpc_port`.. just make `start_rpc` true in your `cassandra.yaml` and set `kundera.port` to `9160` in `persistence.xml`

Comment: @karthikmanchala The same error it shows, even after making the required changes. My `native_transport_port` is 9042 itself and I changed `start_rpc` flag to true, restarted my system so as to restart Cassandra. But still the same error is shown: 
`com.impetus.kundera.KunderaException: All hosts are down. please check servers manully.`

@karthikmanchala can we have a talk over mail or some chat medium ? If you could spare a little time from your valuable time ?

Answer (score 0):

used below config and it works fine on my system..

updated cassandra.yaml:
FROM:
start_rpc: false
TO:
start_rpc: true

Persistence.xml:

unit name mentioned below is random which will be used to access this particular persistence.

keyspace name is the name of the table created in cassandra.

```
<persistence-unit name="persistence">
        <provider>com.impetus.kundera.KunderaPersistence</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="kundera.nodes" value="localhost" />
            <property name="kundera.port" value="9160" />
            <property name="kundera.keyspace" value="trial1" />
            <property name="kundera.dialect" value="cassandra" />
                <property name="kundera.client.lookup.class" value="com.impetus.client.cassandra.thrift.ThriftClientFactory" />

            <property name="kundera.pool.size.max.active" value="500" />
            <property name="kundera.pool.size.max.total" value="500" />
        </properties>
```

Comment: I got solved with the problem, my problem got solved making some changes in persistence.xml and build.sbt itself. I am using Cassandra 2.2.4 version, and I have been unable to take backup using nodetool from the terminal. Any idea regarding this ? It tell me some error as
`nodetool: Failed to connect to 'localhost:7199' - ConnectException: 'Connection refused'.`